# Connect laravel jenssegers to mongodb atlas cluster

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel, jenssegers-mongodb, mongodb-atlas

I'am starting with Mongodb atlas and i trying  to connect my laravel/jenssegers project to the cluster i config  my conf/database

```
'mongodb' => [
  'driver'   => 'mongodb',
  'host'     => env('DB_HOST'),
  'port'     => env('DB_PORT', '27017'),
  'database' => env('DB_DATABASE'),
  'username' => env('DB_USERNAME'),
  'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD'),
  'options'  => [
      'database' => 'admin' // sets the authentication database required by mongo 3
  ]
  ],
```

And my .env file

```
DB_HOST="xxxx-shard-00-00-uggj0.mongodb.net"
DB_PORT=27017
DB_DATABASE=xxx
DB_USERNAME=xxx
DB_PASSWORD=xxx
```

And i get this error

> No suitable servers found (`serverSelectionTryOnce` set): [connection closed calling ismaster on 'xxxx-shard-00-00-uggj0.mongodb.net:27017'

I cold conect with Mongodb Compass without problem.

My Atlas  **Ip Whitelist** is open (0.0.0.0/0).

Am I missing something?

Comment: You need the entire connection string from Atlas, containing all replica set nodes. Also, as an aside: with all of the recent mongodb hacks, and the fact Atlas sets up a mandatory IP whitelist, I'm surprised you simply opened it up to all traffic.

Comment: Where i need to put the atlas string? Well i'm trying first to obtain connection and then secure the cluster

Comment: Try putting the entire host string in `DB_HOST` - remember, every Atlas deployment is on a replica set - you need all hosts.

Comment: i get >(1/1) AuthenticationException
Authentication failed. But password and databace are corret.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In Laravel, Use 'dsn' key in config/database.php as shown below to mention the complete cluster url.

```
'mongodb_conn' => [
        'driver' => 'mongodb',
        'dsn'=>'mongodb://username:password@host1,host2/database?ssl=true&replicaSet=replicaSet&authSource=admin',
        'database' => 'my_data',
    ]
```

Comment: You need to have SSL enabled on your server in order for this to work.

Comment: Prior to moving to Atlas this was not necessary for us. We used Mlab for years and the settings in the .env file were sufficient. After switching to Atlas, the Laravel project would not write to the MongoDB tables in the Atlas cluster - until I used these settings in the config/database.php file. Thanks!

Comment: @RandallClintsman Did you mean ssl on mongodb server or application server. ?

Answer (score 3):

Following works for me, MongoDB Atlas and Laravel 5.7:

update `config/database.php`:

```
'mongodb' => [
            'driver' => 'mongodb',
            'dsn' => 'mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@cluster0.kxxi7.mongodb.net/mydatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority',
            'database' => 'mydatabase',
        ],
```

Set your connection string at `dsn` and db name at `database`.

Answer (score 2):

By default, when assembling the connection string, the Jenssegers\Mongodb package assembles a DSN that starts with mongodb://. In order to connect to a mongoDB atlas instance, the DSN needs to start with mongodb+srv://.

The simplest and most flexible way to handle this is to add the following entry to your .env:

```
MONGO_DB_BASE_URI=mongodb+srv://
```

Then, in your database.php, your mongodb entry should look like the following:

```
    'mongodb' => [
        'driver' => 'mongodb',
        'host' => env('MONGO_DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'port' => env('MONGO_DB_PORT', 27017),
        'database' => env('MONGO_DB_DATABASE'),
        'username' => env('MONGO_DB_USERNAME'),
        'password' => env('MONGO_DB_PASSWORD'),
        'options' => [],
        'dsn' => env('MONGO_DB_BASE_URI','mongodb://').env('MONGO_DB_HOST', 'localhost')
    ],
```

This gives you control over whether you're connecting to a local instance - in which case you can use a DSN of mongodb://, or a cloud instance such as Atlas - in which case you use a DSN of mongodb+srv://.

Comment: I didn't expect this to work since I didn't knew I was using mongoDB atlas instance. But it did work!

Answer (score 0):

```
 'mongodb' => [
        'driver'   => 'mongodb',
        'host'     => [
                       'abc-00-00.mongodb.net',
                        'abc-00-01.mongodb.net',
                        'abc-00-02.mongodb.net'
                    ],
        'port'     => env('MONGO_DB_PORT', 27017),
        'database' => env('MONGO_DB_DATABASE'),
        'username' => env('MONGO_DB_USERNAME'),
        'password' => env('MONGO_DB_PASSWORD'),
        'options'  => [
            'ssl'        => 'true',
            'replicaSet' => 'abc-0',
            'authSource' => 'admin',
            'retryWrites' => 'true', 
           'w' => 'majority'
       ]
    ],
```

**This works for laravel 6 and MongoDB 1.2 or later with MongoDB atlas**