# MongoDB Atals connect with Laravel

Tags: laravel, mongodb

Laravel, Use 'dsn' key in config/database.php as shown below to mention the complete cluster url.

'mongodb' => [
        'driver' => 'mongodb',
        'dsn'=>'mongodb://username:password@host1,host2/database?ssl=true&replicaSet=replicaSet&authSource=admin',
        'database' => 'my_data',
    ]

Comment: You appear to have [simply copied a answer to an existing question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45286932/2313887) as your question. Is there some question you actually intended to ask?