# Cannot Create SSL client. SSL not enabled in build

Tags: laravel, apache, composer-php, mongodb-atlas

I've been migrating databases from mLab to MongoDB Atlas (mLab is being terminated Nov 10th). I've been trying to put make a mongo url dsn connection to connect to my Atlas cluster. However, when I put in the connection, I get this error:

**MongoDB \ Driver \ Exception \ InvalidArgumentException
Cannot create SSL client. SSL is not enabled in this build.**

I have been told this is how you connect to MongoDB Atlas from this source [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44979599/connect-laravel-jenssegers-to-mongodb-atlas-cluster)

Database.php:

```
   'connections' => [

    'sqlite' => [
        'driver' => 'sqlite',
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', database_path('database.sqlite')),
        'prefix' => '',
        'foreign_key_constraints' => env('DB_FOREIGN_KEYS', true),
    ],

            'mongodb' => [
                'driver' => 'mongodb',
                'dsn'=> env('DB_DSN'),
                'database' => env('DB_DATABASE'),
            ],
```

my .env file:

```
DB_DSN=mongodb://****username:****password@*****-shard-00-00.d4sg0.mongodb.net:27017,*****-shard-00-01.d4sg0.mongodb.net:27017,*****-shard-00-02.d4sg0.mongodb.net:27017/****database?ssl=true&replicaSet=atlas-xn698l-shard-0&authSource=admin&retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

Project Specs:
Laravel,
Apache,
MongoDB,
Composer using Git Bash

Comment: I have learned that MongoDB Atlas requires SSL for access. Will need to figure out how to Enable SSL on my heroku server.

Comment: Are you sure this is in any way related to Composer or Apache?

Comment: @NicoHaase Well I'm just not sure how to enable SSL on my application, which uses Composer and Apache.

Comment: How does your application "use" Composer? Usually, you install dependencies using Composer, and don't use it afterwards